# How to group the results from NSMetadataQuery

Tags: macos, cocoa, spotlight, nsmetadataquery

I am performing a query (NSMetadataQuery) on the local data as spotlight performs and sorting the results as per modification date of the files, everything is working fine till this point.
BUT i am not able to understand how can we group the results, for example i want applications in one group, documents in other and images in images group (similar to what spotlight does), 
can anyone suggest how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Using kMDItemKind for your sort (or sub-sort) descriptor should work.